# Dúvida com relação ao NodeJs e mongoose

Tags: node.js

Olá comecei a estudar nodejs e estou com uma dúvida com relação a conexões com banco de dados e relacionamentos,
Utilizando o mongoose eu fiz esse schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //propriedades / campos no db
    nome:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    preco:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    }
});

ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate); //paginar a reposta

mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema); // registrando o model na aplicação  ( toda aplicação vai saber que existe um model product com essas colunas no db)
```

Mas ai então me surgiu uma dúvida quando pensei em um relacionamento, um exemplo (simples apenas para tentar entender a solução):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é como eu conseguiria fazer esses modelos no nodeJs o mongoose seria a melhor opção nesse caso?

No caso eu teria que criar, produtoCategoria e categoria também? Mas como eu relacionaria esses 2 com produtoCategoria?

Ficaria grato se alguém pudesse me ajudar com essa dúvida.

Comment: mongoose é uma coneccao a MongoDB, que é uma base de dados nao relacional, veja tutoriais sobre o que são e como se usam as bases de dados por documentos. Nao se fazem relacoes assim, tenta-se ter tudo num só documento para ser muito mais simples e rapido aceder aos dados... nao é necessário esquema de dados uma vez que é tudo JSON e nao há limite de esquema...

Comment: @balexandre vou dar uma olhada, como é mais rápido e mais simples seria melhor do que relacionais ? hehe vc poderia me falar alguns pontos negativos dele? E vc indicaria utilizar ele ? ou tem situações que não é mt viável utilizar ele.

Comment: tem tantos artigos e videos no YouTube com os pontos bons e maus que nem vale a pena responder aqui, pois preciso de muito mais linhas para escrever :) [olhe aqui um video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZS_kXvOeQ5Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, você tem duas Collection, e você está querendo criar uma terceira Collection que referencie as duas anteriores. Com isso o código fica mais ou menos assim:

### Schema produtoCategoria

```js
const ProdutoCategoriaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
produto:{
    type: mongoose.schema.types.objectId, 
    ref: 'Product', // esse nome faz referência ao nome que colocou na Collection
    require: true
},
categoria:{
    type: mongoose.schema.types.objectId, 
    ref: 'categoria', 
    require: true
},

});
```

Sugiro que você veja esse vídeo onde é aplicado algo similar a esse seu problema:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAZdUyIV3ms

> Rocketseat: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSfwM5u0Kce6Cce8_S72olg

Comment: Era isso man vlw!!

Comment: Isso ai mano. Continue assim!